# How is it possiblle - Although one or More Error Occured [Reverted] Contract Execution Completed?

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation

How is it possible that the txn is reverted due to some error but completed?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc35fde759557f7742224373ea0777cc7ec36bac98dd678aa621ab96063c29e1c

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. I reached out to them and this is what they have replied `yes it's a known issue with our ERC223 implementation. There's a SIP coming to remove our ERC223 support.`